# Getting error error when filtering array React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I am building a simple checkbox component in React Native, I am trying to make some script to add and delete selected choice from an array of selected choices.
I am using the `Array.filter()` function to check whether an item is in the array - however I get this error:

```
selected.filter is not a function. 
(In 'selected.filter(function (c) {
      return c === choice;
})', 'selected.filter' is undefined)
```

Here is my code:

```babel
const Select = ({ multichoice, isMultiple }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([])

  const includes = choice => (
    selected.filter( c => c === choice ).length
  )

  const toggleSelected = choice => { 
    if ( includes(choice) ) setSelected( selected.filter( c => c != choice ) )
    else setSelected( selected.push(choice) )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.selectContainer}>
      {multichoice.map(choice =>
        <Option choice={choice} toggleSelected={toggleSelected} selected={includes(choice)}/>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.push` on an Array, it returns what you pushed to the array, not the what the array you called the function on.  So instead of

```
setSelected( selected.push(choice) )
```

use

```
setSelected([...selected, choice])
```

This will add the `choice` to the end of your current `selected` array and then update that with the hook.

Comment: Thank you very much, I missed that - it still doesn't seem to work. It is now giving the error Maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: If that's the case, then we will need to see more than the code you've posted here.  I would suggest writing a new question because that is outside the bounds of this current question.

Comment: Now worries, looked like I have fixed it (mainly with your help) thank you very much!